# Grub entries for more than one Window OS?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have on my hard disk three operating systems -

- Windows 10
- Windows 7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3

On the grub screen I have only one option for Windows. To boot to either of the windows version, I first have to select the windows (loader) from Grub Menu and then the specific window version from the Windows native boot menu.

Is it possible to have two separate entries for each windows version on the grub menu itself? All three operating system are on the same hard disk, of course, in different partitions.

Comment: All things are possible:  Related: http://www.multibooters.co.uk/multiboot.html

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you have try with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 more easy : but in spanish http://www.ehowenespanol.com/agregar-sistema-operativo-lista-del-menu-del-gestor-arranque-grub-ubuntu-como_201197/#page=6